# Timer implementation for webpage

Tags: javascript, timer

I have implemented timer using `localstorage`. It is working fine.

But If I keep a break point after timer starts, Timer blocks. Once it crosses the breakpoints, timer resumes from the value where it stops due to breakpoint.

Once the timer reaches 00:00 or user submits, I have to send the data to the server. But the problem is how do I validate that user didn't do any hack like pausing the timer by setting up a breakpoint.

Assume a case, My timer value is 5 minutes. User had a break point for two points and done changes in another two minutes. User submits at 4th minute. It is valid from timer perspective but not valid actually.

Another user really takes 4 minutes to complete. It is valid. In this case, he didn't have any break points.

How do I avoid this mismatch?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using `localStorage`? Do you need the timer to carry across page navigation or between sessions? (If it's all within one page you don't need `localStorage`.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks for your comment. I used so that user cannot modify the timer. If there is an option, please educate me

Comment: If the value of the timer is stored in `localStorage` the user can modify it without needing breakpoints, they can just open the dev console and type `localStorage.yourTimerName = something`. It would be better to record the start time on the server-side and then on submit use *that* in a server-side calculation to double-check they didn't hack the client-side timer.

Comment: Thanks @nnnnnn. I will try the same

Answer (score 0):

At the point when the timer starts log the time (and date). Compare that with the time (and date) when the timer stops. Validate the difference in time before allowing the user to submit